# string writing in python serial Port on Raspberrypi

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I am implementing SIM900 interface in RPi using python language. 
However, there is a problem in sending string in port.write() function.

Here is my code:

```
# This line has to write on serial port
port.write(b'AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET"\r\n')
```

The above line works well...

Now my requirement is the string `TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET` which has to read from command line, and I need to append that string with `b'AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","xxxx"\r\n'`.

But when I am trying to read the APN name into variable and after appending it is not working, the code lines are

```
# AP ="TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET"-string read from serial input
AP = gsm.read() 
t1 = "AT+SAPBR=3,1,"
t2 = '"APN",'
t3 = AP
t4 = '\r\n'
t = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4
```

The output of it in python is as follows:

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET"\r\n'
```

It looks like the line which I need, but when I write in gsm.write(t)
it gives an error, I even tried with

```
gsm.write(byte(t))
gsm.write(t.encode())
```

But, it still does not work.

Comment: you would certainly need to provide what error you are seeing ... and what "fails" means ... you might also want to `print(repr(t))` to see the actual representation

Comment: does AP include the double quotes? otherwise you'll have to add them…

Comment: AP is string, If I include double quotes t3="AP" store only AP not content of AP!!!

Comment: I tried running this, but `t` doesn't print as shown. It doesn't print those double inverted commas enclosing `TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET`. Based on given `AP` input it prints `'AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN",TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET\r\n'`. This is not same as one in `port.write(...)`. 
I tried changing `t2 = '"APN",\"'` and `t4 = '\"\r\n'`. Doing this it prints `'AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET"\r\n'` which is same as `port.write`

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using this code with os module that standard in Python:

```
import os

os.system(b'echo -e "AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET\"\r\n" >> ttyAMA0')
```

Best regards

Comment: Also, you may use pyserial.